# What is the difference between The Lay of the Children of Hurin found in The Lays of Beleriand and The Children of Hurin?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, adaptation-comparison, children-of-hurin

I understand that the tales of Turin Turambar, son of Hurin, are partially located in The Silmarillion, Unfinished Tales and The Lays of Beleriand. 
What is the difference between the The Lay of the Children of Hurin found in The Lays of Beleriand and the later completed book The Children of Hurin by Christopher Tolkien?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference is that one is written in verse and the other in prose.

> To Thangorodrim       was the Thalion bome,
>   that mountain that meets       the misty skies
>   on high over the hills       that Hithlum sees
>   blackly brooding       on the borders of the North.
>   There stretched on the stone       of steepest peak
>   in bonds unbreakable       they bound him living;
>   there the lord of woe       in laughter stood,
>   there cursed him for ever       and his kindred all
>   that should walk and wander       in woe’s shadow
>   to a doom of death       and dreadful end.
>   There the mighty man       unmovéd sat,
>   but unveiled was his vision       that he viewed afar
>   with eyes enchanted       all earthly things,
>   and the weird of woe       woven darkly
>   that fell on his folk—       a fiend’s torment.
>   <sub>(The Lay of The Children of Hurin - Second Verison - Lines 233-247)</sub>

> 'You shall see and you shall confess that I do not lie,' said Morgoth. And taking Húrin back to Angband he set him in a chair of stone upon a high place of Thangorodrim, from which he could see afar the land of Hithlum in the west and the lands of Beleriand in the south. There he was bound by the power of Morgoth; and Morgoth standing beside him cursed him again and set his power upon him, so that he could not move from that place, nor die, until Morgoth should release him.
>   'Sit now there,' said Morgoth, 'and look out upon the lands where evil and despair shall come upon those whom you have delivered to me. For you have dared to mock me, and have questioned the power of Melkor, Master of the fates of Arda. Therefore with my eyes you shall see, and with my ears you shall hear, and nothing shall be hidden from you.'
>   <sub>*The Children of Hurin* - Chapter III</sub>

There are other differences as well. The Lay version is much more detailed uses an earlier version of the story, and cuts off about halfway through.

> These interrelated but independent stories had from far back stood out from the long and complex history of Valar, Elves and Men in Valinor and the Great Lands; and in the years that followed his abandonment of the Lost Tales before they were completed my father turned away from prose composition and began work on a long poem with the title Túrin son of Húrin and Glórund the Dragon, later changed in a revised version to The Children of Húrin. This was in the earlier 1920s, when he held appointments at the University of Leeds. For this poem he employed the ancient English alliterative metre (the verse form of Beowulf and other Anglo-Saxon poetry), imposing on modern English the demanding patterns of stress and 'initial rhyme' observed by the old poets: a skill in which he achieved great mastery, in very different modes, from the dramatic dialogue of The Homecoming of Bëorhtnoth to the elegy for the men who died in the battle of the Pelennor Fields. The alliterative Children of Húrin was by far the longest of his poems in this metre, running to well over two thousand lines; yet he conceived it on so lavish a scale that even so he had reached no further in the narrative than the assault of the Dragon on Nargothrond when he abandoned it. With so much more of the Lost Tale still to come it would have needed on this scale many more thousands of lines; while a second version, abandoned at an earlier point in the narrative, is about double the length of the first version to that same point.
>   <sub>*The Children of Hurin* - Appendix 1: The Evolution of the Great Tales</sub>

The version published in *The Children of Hurin* combines the version of the text which was published in *Unfinished Tales* with the other *prose* versions of the text and uses a bit of editing to ensure consistency. A more detailed account can be found in the second appendix of *The Children of Hurin*, "The Composition of the Text".